# Ayuda con el error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

Buenas, llevo cerca de 2 días tratando de solucionar este error, y no se como solucionarlo. La idea es que la app se conecte a un web-service y al celular le llegen los datos que están. acá está el codigo.
Gracias! 
ps: estoy recién aprendiendo a programar.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    EditText mac,nombre,patente,rut,empresa,containers,conectado;
    Button Iniciar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        mac = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mac);
        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        patente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.patente);
        rut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rut);
        empresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empresa);
        containers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.containers);
        conectado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conectado);
        Iniciar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Iniciar);


        Iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new ConsultarDatos().execute("http://192.168.50.22:82/webservice/listarBeacon.php");

            }
        });

    }



    private class ConsultarDatos extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        private final String USER_AGENT = "Chrome";
        private final String SERVER_PATH = "http://192.168.50.22:82/webservice/";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {

            try{
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            }catch (IOException e){
                return "Incapaz de recuperar la página web";
            }
        }

        @NonNull
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private String getJSON(){

            StringBuffer response = null;

            try {
                //Generar la URL
                String url = SERVER_PATH+"listarBeacon.php";
                //Creamos un nuevo objeto URL con la url donde pedir el JSON
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                //Creamos un objeto de conexión
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                //Añadimos la cabecera
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                // Enviamos la petición por POST
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                //Capturamos la respuesta del servidor
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
                System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

                try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }   //Mostramos la respuesta del servidor por consola
                    System.out.println("Respuesta del servidor: "+response);
                    System.out.println();
                    //cerramos la conexión
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            return response.toString();
        }

        private void getData(String json) throws ParseException, JSONException {
            System.out.println("INFORMACIÓN OBTENIDA DE LA BASE DE DATOS:");
            //Crear un Objeto JSON a partir del string JSON
            JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject o = (JSONObject) p.parse(json);
            //Convertir el objeto JSON en un array
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) o.get("listaBeacon");
            for(Object pro: array){
                JSONObject tmp = (JSONObject) pro;
                Log.i("Mac: ",tmp.get("mac").toString());
                Log.i("nombre: ",tmp.get("nombre").toString());
                Log.i("patente: ",tmp.get("patente").toString());
                Log.i("rut: ",tmp.get("rut").toString());
                Log.i("empresa: ",tmp.get("empresa").toString());
                Log.i("containers: ", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tmp.get("containers").toString())));
                Log.i("conectado: ", String.valueOf(Boolean.valueOf(tmp.get("conectado").toString())));
            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            try {
                getData(getJSON());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }





    }



    /*coje la url que le demos, */
    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException{
        Log.i("URL",""+myurl);
        myurl = myurl.replace(" ","%20");
        InputStream is = null;
        //Sólo muestran los primeros 500 caracteres del contenido de la
        // página web recuperada
        int len = 500;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(myurl);//convierte el objeto myurl en objeto url
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//crea la conexion httpurlconection y la abre
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /*milisegundios*/);//tiempo de lectura
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);//tiempo de conexion
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            //Start the query
            conn.connect();//se conecta
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("respuesta","LA RESPUESTA ES : " + response);//si hace la conexoon la respuesta es 200
            is = conn.getInputStream();//lo que responda la url lo guardará en is


            //convierte el InputStream a String

            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);//se evia el input string y la longitud
            return contentAsString;

        }finally {
            if(is != null){
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public String readIt (InputStream stream, int len) throws  IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        Reader reader = null;
       // reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }





}
```

Acá está el error.

> 04-27 15:24:01.465 17040-17040/com.arieloft.skylo.pruebaconexion
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.arieloft.skylo.pruebaconexion, PID: 17040
>                                                                                      android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                          at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
>                                                                                          at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
>                                                                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>                                                                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>                                                                                          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>                                                                                          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
>                                                                                          at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.arieloft.skylo.pruebaconexion.MainActivity$ConsultarDatos.getJSON(MainActivity.java:105)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.arieloft.skylo.pruebaconexion.MainActivity$ConsultarDatos.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:149)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.arieloft.skylo.pruebaconexion.MainActivity$ConsultarDatos.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:70)
>                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Estas realizando una tarea en el hilo principal, debes agregar tu LogCat, hay informaciónd este error en el sitio. Agrega el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat

Comment: Agrega la última versión de tu código, en este código al parecer no tienes ese problema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas realizando una conexión en

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            try {
                getData(getJSON());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

debes realizarla en `doInBackground()`, modifica tu método :

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {

            try{
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            }catch (IOException e){
                return "Incapaz de recuperar la página web";
            }


                try {
                    getData(getJSON());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
```